# Como fazer um ListView em formato de tabela no Xamarin Forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin-forms

Preciso criar um ListView que fique semelhante a essa imagem, portanto não faço ideia de como fazer, pois nunca usei o Xamarin, estou aprendendo na aplicação que estou desenvolvendo.
[image: Dessa forma ou parecida deverá ficar o ListView no app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa foi a forma que encontrei para conseguir criar uma tabela semelhante a que eu publiquei:

```
<Grid  ColumnSpacing="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                         <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="#" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="coluna0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  SeparatorColor="White"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"/>
                    <Label Text="Colaborador" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="coluna1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  SeparatorColor="White"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"/>
                    <Label Text="Cliente" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <ListView x:Name="coluna2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"  SeparatorColor="White"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"/>
                    <Label Text="Duração" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="coluna3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"  SeparatorColor="White"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"/>
                </Grid>
```